# Pandas: How do I create a new index based on a groupby?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is it possible to transform Table 1 to table 2, where a new multi-index table is created so that a specific 'class_section' grouping has its own index order? Is using group by required? or is there another way I can do this by split.apply.combine technique?

Thanks in advance.

Table 1

|  | name | movie_watch_count | class_section |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Morris | 2 | 2 |
| 1 | Gertie | 3 | 1 |
| 2 | Kristal | 3 | 1 |
| 3 | Roslyn | 4 | 2 |
| 4 | Tari | 7 | 2 |
| 5 | Dewayne | 1 | 1 |
| 6 | Edward | 6 | 2 |
| 7 | Frank | 0 | 2 |

Table 2

|  | global_index | group_index | name | movie_watch_count | class_section |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | Gertie | 3 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | Kristal | 3 | 1 |
| 2 | 5 | 2 | Dewayne | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 | Morris | 2 | 2 |
| 4 | 3 | 1 | Roslyn | 4 | 2 |
| 5 | 4 | 2 | Tari | 7 | 2 |
| 6 | 6 | 3 | Edward | 6 | 2 |
| 7 | 7 | 4 | Frank | 0 | 2 |

Answer (score 0):

For an independent indexing inside each group we can use `groupby(...).cumcount()`:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

data = '''  name    movie_watch_count   class_section
0   Morris  2   2
1   Gertie  3   1
2   Kristal     3   1
3   Roslyn  4   2
4   Tari    7   2
5   Dewayne     1   1
6   Edward  6   2
7   Frank   0   2'''

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep=' \t', engine='python')
df['group_index'] = df.groupby('class_section').cumcount()
```